# Can't print out a string in C

Tags: c

I've been learning C with a book and I tried one of its programs on my Linux PC with gcc, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getoneline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int line_length, max_length;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max_length = 0;
    while ((line_length=getoneline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (line_length > max_length)
        {
            max_length = line_length;
            copy(longest, line);
        }

    if (max_length > 0)
        printf ("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

int getoneline(char s[], int limit)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i < limit - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

It is the same in the book and it's supposed to find the longest line in some text and the output it. However, nothing gets outputted, as if the variable longest disappeared after the while loop. I can print it inside, though, but that's not what I want.

What's going wrong?

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: If this code is what the book recommends, I'd get a new book. There are several small bugs in there.

Comment: That's intriguing, @melpomene — I can see a couple of things I'd do differently, but I don't see the full-on "bugs" you say you see; my compiler set to my normal degree of fussiness (`gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes long83.c -o long83`) wittereth not, either.  Which problems are you seeing?  There are examples of `int main()` in the standard, though it's not what I'd write.  If the line is longer than 998 characters plus newline, then it will be split (but that will be regarded as the longest line) — that's a reasonable design decision.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Potential integer overflow in `i` in `copy`. `c` may be used uninitialized in `getoneline` (if `limit < 2`). The code silently cuts up long lines (longer than 998 characters) and treats the parts as separate lines.

Comment: @melpomene: no risk of integer overflow in `copy()` with the given code; it will be copying not more than 1000 bytes.  If `limit` is passed to `getoneline()` as 1, 0, or negative, then yes, `c` could be uninitialized in `getoneline()` (but that isn't going to be a problem with this code — it could be if it was used elsewhere).  The line length is a reasonable design decision when the book has not yet reached dynamic memory allocation.  I think you are applying too stringent a standard to the code — tutorial code does not have to meet full production quality, and it isn't gratuitously bad.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I disagree. If the functions are not meant to be generally reusable units, why extract them from the main logic in the first place? A tutorial should teach good practices because beginners will blindly copy/paste code into their programs (see also: StackOverflow). In particular `getoneline` is weirdly inconsistent: It contains some pretty fancy logic for what's supposed to be beginner code (the `for` loop), but also unnecessarily repeated code (`s[i] = c`, `++i`) and the uninitialized variable bug that is entirely due to the convoluted logic.

Comment: @melpomene I compile it with gcc, run it in the shell and then paste some lorem ipsum into the program. Also, this is the book by B. W. Kernighan and D. M. Ritchie, which my lecturer recommends :/ Also there isn't much choice in my library.

Comment: @guben Be specific: Compile it with gcc how? What's the command line? Run it in the shell how? What's the command line? Paste into the program how? What keys or buttons are you pressing? What happens? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @melpomene It goes like this: gcc maxline.c then ./a.out then right-click paste then (this is what I was doing wrong) press Enter instead of Ctrl-D
I had been expecting to see the longest line, but the program didn't print anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me! Try running the program and entering a few lines of text. Then press Ctrl-D so that `getchar` returns an `EOF`, causing the program to break out of the while loop and print the longest line

I would point out that there are about a million better ways to write this code that are less confusing. Without getting into all the reasons for this, I sincerely recommend following the 'get a new book' advice in the comments.

Comment: @TanoFotang, that code would be seriously frowned upon by an modern coding standard and get flagged in a code review. I suggest looking for a book that teaches better style.

Comment: So it was Ctrl-D that was missing. Yikes, I was pressing Enter this whole chapter. Thanks!